# 3Sum on a sorted array. O(NlogN) implementation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

Given a SORTED array of n elements. Find three numbers from the array that will add up to a given number k.

Here's what I have thought till now:
We start with two variables L and H that store the indices of the first and last element in the array. Add the elements at these indices and subtract it from k and store it in a variable, say z.
Now since the array is sorted, I can binary search for z in the array. If z is found I have the three numbers. If z is not found, I have to either increment L or decrement H.

Now I can't figure out when to increment L or when to decrement H. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

> **Unsolved problem in computer science**: Is there an algorithm to solve the 3SUM problem in time `O(n^(2-e))` for some `e > 0`?

Another quote:

> The current best known algorithm for 3SUM runs in `O(n^2 / (log n / log log n))` time

So there is no known `O(nlogn)` algorithm for this problem. Quadratic algorithm from wikipedia:

```
sort(S);
for i=0 to n-3 do
    a = S[i];
    start = i+1;
    end = n-1;
    while (start < end) do
        b = S[start]
        c = S[end];
        if (a+b+c == 0) then
             output a, b, c;
             // Continue search for all triplet combinations summing to zero.
             end = end - 1
        else if (a+b+c > 0) then
             end = end - 1;
        else
             start = start + 1;
        end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Wiki says: **The algorithm below first sorts the input array and then tests all possible pairs in a careful order that avoids the need to binary search for the pairs in the sorted list, achieving worst-case {\displaystyle O(n^{2})} O(n^{2}) time.** 

Here, It says that it avoids the need to do a binary search, I don't understand why do we have to avoid binary search. Also, in our case, the array is already sorted, can't we use that fact and use binary search to get better results?

Comment: @StillLearning, We avoid binary search, because with binary search complexity will be O(n^2*logn) (two nested loops for a and b, and binary search for c). Sorting is O(n*logn), so it has no influence to overall algorithm complexity.